# Classloading error on entity from other project

Tags: jakarta-ee, classloader

I want to create a entity converter which can be used in the JSF pages of my project.

My project structure is the following:

-- project-ear.ear
|--- project1-ejb.jar
|--- project2-web.war
|--- lib
|---|--- warframework.jar
|---|--- ekbframework.jar

In the lib.jar I have an absctract class `EntityConverter` implementing the JSF Converter logic in the `lib/warframework.jar`.

```
public abstract class EntityConverter implements Converter {
    protected abstract EntityLoader getEntityLoader();

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(value)) return null;

        try {
            String[] split = value.split(":");
            return getEntityLoader().loadEntity(split[0], Long.valueOf(split[1]));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value == null) return null;

        if (value instanceof AbstractEntity) {
            return value.getClass() + ":" + ((AbstractEntity) value).getSid();
        } else {
            return value.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

And a interface `EntityLoader` in the `lib/ejbframework.jar`.

```
public interface EntityLoader {
    AbstractEntity loadEntity(String className, Long sid);
}
```

I am using Mavens WAR-Overlay feature to combine different war-files into one. I have a `project1-web.war` which is included in the `project2-web.war`. 
In that `project1-web.war` I define the concrete implementation of the Converter:

```
@Named
@FacesConverter("concreteEntityConverter")
public class ConcreteEntityConverter extends EntityConverter {
    @Inject
    private ConcreteEntityLoader entityLoader;

    @Override
    protected EntityLoader getEntityLoader() {
        return entityLoader;
    }
}
```

And in the project1-ejb.jar I define the `EntityLoader` implementation:

```
public class ShsEntityLoader implements EntityLoader {
    @Inject
    Logger log;
    @Inject
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public AbstractEntity loadEntity(String className, Long sid) {
        AbstractEntity entity = null;

        try {
            entity = (AbstractEntity) entityManager.find(Class.forName(className), sid);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            log.warn("Could not load entity for class: " + className, ex);
        }

        return entity;
    }
}
```

After deploying the `ear` and triggering the converter, I get following error:

> Could not load entity for class: class de.example.com.user.model.MyEntity: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: class de.example.com.user.model.MyEntity from [Module "deployment.project-ear.ear.project1-ejb.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
>     at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
>     at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
>     at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
>     at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
>     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
>     at de.example.com.common.service.ConcreteEntityLoader.loadEntity(ConcreteEntityLoader.java:30)

The class `de.example.com.user.model.MyEntity` exists in the same jar like the `EntityLoader`. I think, this exception occurs, because the entity converter is called from the `project2-web.war` file, which class loader can not access the classes in `project1-ejb.jar`. Is this correct? What do I have to change, so that the class can be loaded correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem:

My code in `EntityConverter.getAsString()` creates a wrong string representation of the objects :

```
return value.getClass() + ":" + ((AbstractEntity) value).getSid();
```

The result was: `class de.example.com.user.model.MyEntity:1` and not as expected `de.example.com.user.model.MyEntity:1`.

Changing above code to following, makes everything work as expected:

```
return value.getClass().getCanonicalName() + ":" + ((AbstractEntity) value).getSid();
```